# Create ipa file , provisioning ad hoc profile a lot of errors

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using the company developer account that was created some time ago by someone else. I developed an application that is running properly and i test it also on my phone. Now I want to send it to another tester. For this I tried to follow more tutorials but I have the problem with "there is no valid....for this provisioning"
In my keychain access I have at certificates 2 certificates : one iphone developer (under this is a leaf with the key)and one with iphone distribution(this does not jave any leaf and any key )
When i created provisioning profile for testing I had to choos iphone distribution profile (that is not made by me , it was already created)
This profile has an application on the market . 
I just want for this new application to create the ipa file. 
I read on tutorials that i have to do a certificate from keychain acces but i can not add it because there is already an iphone distribution certificate. If i delete this the application that was already post it will be affected?
What can I do to use the same and the new prov profile to be visble and enabled?
Thanks , 
Raluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course applications already on the market will NOT be affected. Create new cert with your key, no way to use cert without key.

Comment: and the old application i have to reload  it on amrket ?

Comment: No. It's already published, signed with Apple cert and so on. Changing your current certs will not affect it in any way. Several times I moved to a new system and had to create new keys and certs - everything will be OK.